# NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(1, 'sgm')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm learning Django framework and I have, in the extend templates part, an Error during template rendering. I have received this error when I add slug field; We get this template error:

> NoReverseMatch at / Reverse for 'product_detail' with arguments '(1, 'sgm')' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['(?P<category_slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)$']

```py
    from django.urls import path
    from shop import views
    app_name='shop'
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
        path('search', views.product_search, name='product_search'),
       
        path('<slug:category_slug>', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    
        path('<slug:slug>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    ]
```

`views.py`

```py
    from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
    from shop.models import Category, Product
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
    from django.core.paginator import Paginator, EmptyPage, PageNotAnInteger
    from wishlist.models import Wishlist, WishlistItem
    from django.contrib.postgres.search import SearchVector
    
    
    def product_list(request, category_slug=None):
        category = None
        categories = Category.objects.all()
        products = Product.objects.filter(available=True)
        if category_slug:
            category = get_object_or_404(Category, slug=category_slug)
    
            products = products.filter(category=category)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        paginator = Paginator(products, 6)
        try:
            products = paginator.page(page)
    
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            products = paginator.page(1)
    
        except EmptyPage:
            products = paginator.page(1)
        is_authenticated = request.user.is_authenticated
        print(is_authenticated)
        if is_authenticated:
            wishlist = Wishlist.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    
            return render(
                request,
                'shop/product/list.html',
                {
                    'category': category,
                    'categories': categories,
                    'products': products,
                    'wishlist': wishlist
                }
            )
    
        else:
            return render(
                request,
                'shop/product/list.html',
                {
                    'category': category,
                    'categories': categories,
                    'products': products,
                }
            )
    
    
    def product_search(request):
        results = None
        try:
            query = request.POST['query']
            results = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=query) |\
                Product.objects.filter(description__icontains=query)
            page = request.GET.get('page')
            paginator = Paginator(results, 6)
            try:
                results = paginator.page(page)
    
            except PageNotAnInteger:
                results = paginator.page(1)
            except EmptyPage:
    
                results = paginator.page(1)
    
            wishlist = None
            return render(
                request,
                'shop/product/list.html',
                {'products': results, 'wishlist': wishlist}
            )
        except KeyError:
            wishlist = None
            "KeyError"
            return render(
                request,
                'shop/product/list.html',
                {'products': results, 'wishlist': wishlist}
            )
    
    
    def product_detail(request, id, slug):
    
        product = get_object_or_404(
            Product,
            id=id,
            slug=slug,
            available=True
        )
    
        return render(
            request,
            'shop/product/detail.html',
            {'product': product}
        )
```

`template`

```html
                {% load static %}
                <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8" />
                    <title>{% block title %}online shop{% endblock %}</title>
                    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="{%  static 'img/save.ico' %}"/>
                    
                    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
                    <meta name="description" content="">
                    <meta name="author" content="">
        
                    <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
                
                
                    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
                    <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/custom.js' %}"></script>
                    <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>
                
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
                
                    <!-- Optional theme -->
                    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
                
                    <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
                    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
                    <link href="{% static 'css/shop-homepage.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
                </head>
                <body>
                    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
                
                      <div class="container">
                        <a  href="/"> <img src="{% static "img/logo.png" %}" height="30px"></a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                
                
                          <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
                
                        <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
                                    <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
                                </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                                </li>
                            
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
                                </li>
                
                                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                                <li class="dropdown ">
                          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> {{ user.username }}<span ></span></a>
                            
                          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:detail_profile' %}" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span> User Settings</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'cart:cart_detail' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Cart <span class="badge">4</span></a></li>
                            <li><a href="{% url 'wishlist:wishlist_detail' %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></span> Wishlist</a></li>
                
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                
                            <li><a href="{% url 'accounts:logout' %}?next=/"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out" aria-hidden="true"></span> Logout</a></li>
                            
                
                            </ul>
                            </li>
                                {% else %}
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:signup' %}" class="nav-link">
                                        <span  aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Register
                
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a href="{% url 'accounts:login' %}" class="nav-link">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in" aria-hidden="true"></span>&nbsp; Login
                
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                {% endif %}
                          </ul>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </nav>
                &nbsp
                    <!-- Page Content -->
                    <div class="container">
                <div id="content">
                        {% block content %}
                        {% endblock %}
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    &nbsp
                    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
                      <div class="container">
                        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; OnlineShop 2018</p>
                      </div>
                    </footer>
                </body>
                </html>
```

`list.html`

```html
    {% extends "shop/base.html" %}
    {% load static %}
    
    {% block title %}
        {% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
    
    {% block content %}
    
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
    
              
              <h3 class="my-4">Products</h3>
              <div class="list-group">
                
                <a href="{% url "shop:product_list" %}" class="list-group-item">All</a>
                {% for c in categories %}
                
                <a href="{{ c.get_absolute_url }}" class="list-group-item">{{ c.name }}</a>
                {% endfor %}
                
              </div>
    
    
              <h3 class="my-4">Search Products</h3>
                   
                <div class="row">
    
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <form action="{% url "shop:product_search" %}" method="post">
                      {% csrf_token %}
                    <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" name="query" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for product...">
                      <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Go!</button>
                      </span>
                    </div><!-- /input-group -->
                  </form>
                  </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                </div><!-- /.row -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-3 -->
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                <div class="row">
    
                <h3></h3>
                <h3 class="my-4">{% if category %}{{ category.name }}{% else %}Products{% endif %}</h3>
                </div>
            <div class="row">
              
    
    
                {% for product in products %}
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 mb-4">
                
                  <div class="card h-100">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                    <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="{% if product.image %}{{ product.image.url }}{% else %}{% static "img/no_image.png" %}{% endif %}">
                    </a>
                  </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <h4 class="card-title">
                        <a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a><br>
                      </h4>
                      <h5>${{ product.price }}</h5>
                      
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer text-center">
                      <small class="text-muted">
                          
                          <a href="{% url  'cart:cart_add' product.id %}" class="btn btn-primary">Add to cart</a>
                          
                          <a href="{% url  'wishlist:wishlist_add' product.id %}" class="btn btn-default">Add to Wishlist</a>
                          
                          
                      </small>
                    </div>
                    
                  </div>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}    
            
    
                
              </div>
              
                
                
              <!-- /.row -->
    
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-9 -->
    
          </div>
    
        
          <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                    
                        <div class="pag_area">
                            <ul class="pagination">
                                {% if products.has_previous %}
                                    <li><a href="?page={{ products.previous_page_number }}">«</a></li>
                                {% else %}
                                    <li class="disabled"><span>«</span></li>
                                {% endif %}
                                {% for i in products.paginator.page_range %}
                                    {% if products.number == i %}
                                        <li class="active"><span>{{ i }} <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></span></li>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <li><a href="?page={{ i }}">{{ i }}</a></li>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% endfor %}
                                {% if products.has_next %}
                                    <li><a href="?page={{ products.next_page_number }}">»</a></li>
                                {% else %}
                                    <li class="disabled"><span>»</span></li>
                                {% endif %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
    
          <!-- /.row -->
    
    
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem you are encountering is that you have multiple URL paths that match the URL you are trying to access.

```
    path('<slug:category_slug>', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),

    path('<slug:slug>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

Both of these paths match a slug - and nothing else. When you try to access the URL at path "/sgm" Django doesn't know which of those two to try to route the request to.

Instead, try changing those URL paths to something like this:

```
    path('category/<slug:category_slug>', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),

    path('detail/<slug:slug>', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
```

Comment: i got same error when changed the  url path.